# why does accessing an array object by name gives undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Why do I get undefined if I try to access a string like this:

```
obj.prop = JSON.stringify(otherObj);
```

Yet if I access it like this:

```
prop = JSON.stringify(otherObj.propertyIwant);
```

it works and gives me the value I want ??

Comment: What is `otherObj`? I'd guess it isn't a stringifyable object.

Comment: Where is `obj` defined?

Comment: check what you have in obj an in otherObj

Comment: 'otherObj' is type object

Comment: obj is defined like this: var obj;

Comment: @Rob That's your problem. `prop` doesn't exist in `obj`, because `obj` has nothing assigned to it. You should define it like: `var obj = {};`

Comment: Have you decalare any proprty "prop" in the object "obj"? Then it will surely throw the error "undefinded". Instead of "obj.prop" try "obj['prop']". Share the code regardig the variable "otherObj" too.

Comment: Sorry to say it. **Unclear what you are asking** :)

Comment: You need a [mcve] and a *clear problem statement*, you've provided neither. The code you've provided isn't enough to reproduce the problem, and the description of the problem isn't clear.

Comment: Thankyou - 'revilheart'  Yours is about the only helpful response here :)

Comment: @Rob — Please don't insult people who are trying to encourage you to ask a coherent question by saying that someone to made massive assumptions about what you left out is the only person being helpful.

Answer (score -1):

So, `stringify` will convert `obj` to a String, which means that trying to access a property on it (as you did with `obj.prop`, will result in `undefined`.

In your second example, you're stringifying a property of an object (assuming `otherObj` is a valid object) and assigning it to a variable.

Comment: That's fair enough, but surely, trying to access a property on it would result in that property being stringified, or at least just convert the object and its property to a string literal.

Undefined tells you absolutely nothing about why or how the bug occurs!

Answer (score -2):

Rob, why are you converting JSON object to the string ?

where you can directory access the property by name and store it in any variable.

Solution:

```
var jObject = {name : 'Rob',age: 20};
var myVar = jObject.age;
```

Comment: Because I'm sending a JSON string to a webapi as a body payload in a POST and the array I'm sending needs to match the back-end model:

plannedRosterEntries.push({"JobNo" : e.jobNo,"EmployeeID" : e.employeeID, "PlanStart" : e.shiftDate, "ShiftLength" : e.shiftHours,
        "DutyCodeID" : Duty_Code, "HAVSIdentified" : havs, "PreShiftNotes" : e.notes, "PlannedShiftByEmployeeId" : e.plannedShiftByEmployeeId,
        "ContractTypeID" : contractTypeID});